# How to place security on a document library such that users only see documents they created?

Tags: document-library, permissions

When using lists, it is easy to specify that users can only see lists that they created (through Advanced Settings).

Is there a similar way to do this with document libraries? Rather than doing item level security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to modify the default view for the document library adding a filter for modified by or created by = [me]

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean a user can't go see the entire list by changing the view... I need "security" on the view as well then.

Comment: If you change the default view this way, then really there is no other view where users could see all.  I would suggest a separate page with a Data View Web Part for viewing all.  The page can be secured.

Comment: This wont stop them opening the Document Library in Explorer view and seeing everything though. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Maybe you can use javascript to hide the button?  By the way, @RobWilson, this filtering idea works for me!  Gratias ago tibi!