# How to create a list of data gotten from many forms?

Tags: infopath, site, forms-library, cross-site

Salve!  I have a handful of subsites, each with a form library that uses infopath content-types.  The user creates a new form document in a the library and then fills out the form.

I want to gather the data from those completed forms (from every subsite) into a single list (on another site) where I can see all the data entered.  I know how to use a CQWP to get a list of the forms (based on content-type), but that doesn't get me a list of data.

I want to see something like this:

```
form1   field1value  field2value
form2   field1value  field2value
```

A fellow in one of the answers [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/how-to-place-security-on-a-document-library-such-that-users-only-see-documents-t) speaks of doing this in a DVWP, but I think that this doesn't exist in 2010; a fellow [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12742/data-view-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010#12751) speaks of it being called `XSLT List View Web Part`, but when I go to "Insert Web Part" in my Page, I don't see that web part listed.

What can I do?  Any ideas?

**[update]**

I asked a separate question here about [how to get a DVWP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52316/where-is-the-dvwp-in-sharepoint-2010), and received a splendid answer.

Answer (score 1):

> called XSLT List View Web Part, but when I go to "Insert Web Part" in
>   my Page, I don't see that web part listed.

"**Insert Web Part**" option lists already published (deployed) to Shaqrepoint webparts.
 **XSLT List View Web Part** is for being <s>created</s> designed dynamically based on a data source content.

You can do it from browser but if you do it from **Sharepoint Designer 21010** (SPD), you will clearly see its markup or tag  **XsltListViewWebPart** as well as its code.

So, in **SPD** create a WebPart page (Site Pages > there are many ways how to further do it, quite obvious.

There, in **Design**  view, in a placeholder I usually insert a few line breaks in order to be more comfortable with further editing.
Then click **Insert** tab, on ribbon > **DataView** > choose a (document) library under Documents and Libraries section of dropdown list of choices.
Then, you will clearly see **WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart**

You can repeat it inserting other **XsltListViewWebPart**  web part.

Though, answering your title question, you most probably will want to make first a specific/separate **data source**.

IMO, Sharepoint is good for simple OOTB gathering of data but not its (or "their, I am not good in English) flexible (or advanced) management (and presentation). If you want to manage efficiently and dynamically, on the fly, (large amount of) data then you most probably should use Database Management System like MS SQL Server, here are some keywords from MSSQL:

- MS **BI** - Business Intelligence

  - **SSAS** - MS SQL Server Analysis Services,

    - DM - Data-mining
  - **SSRS** - MS SQL Server Reporting Services

    - etc.

**Update:**
Now, after answering, I've noticed that the question is tagged with "infopath", though, IMO, Infopath is quite unrelated and divergent to **XSLT List View Web Part** usage

> I want to gather the data from those completed forms (from every
>   subsite)

You should **promote** fields to sharepoint fields during **form template publishing** in order to be able to easily access the same data from sharepoint fields.

In Infopath Designer, you create data connections/sources to sharepoint (form or doument) library or list, insert controls for fields and links them (with Xpath) to whatever field data  from whatever source you wish in any combination.

Comment: Gennady, this is a good answer; you get my vote - however I will have to try it out before I mark it solved...  The question was tagged infopath because the data to be listed was generated from an infopath form content-type and resides in a form-library; some folks might think that is an important detail.

Comment: BGM, thanks. I did not pretend (and would have never dared to attempt) to answer your title question (because it is multi-facet interweaved with many unknowns business and system analysis project assignment), I had an answer to your body question which was too lengthy for a comment. I would have felt more comfortable if you've had different questions in different posts.

Comment: Well, my title question reflects what I really want; my body explains how I have attempted to get there.  Folks always dig for details.  I don't care what way to do it, I just need to do it *somehow*, which is why the question was broad.

Comment: I do not see any problems to do what is asked in the title. And there are a zillion variants how to do it but I am not going to bloat by them my answer. Note that your question is formulated ambiguously... For example, how to choose which of the Field1Value to show in first line (for form1) and in second line (for form2)... What is the problem in showing values from different forms - just bind controls to  secondary/receive data connection/source?